# What can I do when pattern matching with grepl in R is not working when it jolly well should?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a specific problem that is darn weird. I generated a Microsoft Form that asks respondents to rank ten possible initiatives in the order that they believe would have most impact to least impact. Microsoft Forms allowed me to export the raw data as an excel spreadsheet which I read into R and then reshaped from wide to long. I wanted to retain only rows for four of the initiatives.

The description of each initiative was very wordy with full sentences and explanations including punctuation. For the purposes of recognizing which initiative was which, it was easy to truncate the lengthy description using a substring of the first 40 characters. If I truncated by using only the first 10 characters then it was difficult, just by glancing, to tell which initiative was which.

I used a `grep` (and its data.table equivalent of `%chin%`) to select just the rows containing the 40-character strings I wanted. I kept on getting a return of nothing. Nothing matched. I struggled for hours and turned to StackOverflow only to find that when I put the long strings or the whole data.table through dput the problem was fixed.

I and @r2evans suspected that the very long strings that have been exported from Microsoft Forms via Microsoft Excel were contaminated with demons/non-standard character encoding.

How do you check for demons hiding in strings and exorcise them? Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: When I run your first two lines of code (`inits <- c(...)` and `grepl(...)`), where you get all false, I get the correct F,T,F,F,F,F. You may want to check for unicode characters in your strings that might not have transferred to your sample data here on SO.

Comment: Something very funny is going on. This happened to me on two very different computing environments. I then went back to my machine and I too, could not reproduce it.  My minimal simple example was stripped out of a more complex problem that I was having with data.table. When I have my original data.table open I run into the problem. I tried to make a minimal example of that but when I dput that and read it in my problem goes away. Something is happening in my data.table so that this fails, `long.poll[initiative=="Surgeon sits down next to bed to talk to patient o"]`. Suggestions?

Comment: And then after that data.table fail, things seem to go wrong. If I populate inits from my data.table like so `inits <- long.poll[, unique(initiative)]` then I get my whole problem all over again just as I did in the original question. A long pattern fails and short one words correctly.

Comment: Can you share a little more about the organization of the raw `.xlsx` that you start with and what you're trying to get out of it? It might be easier to solve this in some other way.

Comment: Try to replace all non-breaking spaces with "normal" spaces.

Comment: Could it be that there is some unicode goblin monster lurking in my original data.table and the process of `dput()` is exorcising the demon.  Perhaps I need some kind of function along the lines of as.SimplestCharacterSetOnly() such that it would be long.poll[ , initiative := as.SimplestCharacterSetOnly(initiative)]

Comment: The fact that it fails only in the longer pattern suggests that the problematic character(s) are in that later portion. Can you iteratively test chunks if the string to narrow down the issue?

Comment: does `grepl("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", vec)` return any true? Perhaps that'll find a character that isn't "normal ascii". (`vec` here is from your data.table that produces the problems.)

Comment: It was all TRUE. Early in my code I used a line such as this. `poll[ , impact := str_replace_all(string = impact, pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", replacement = "")]`. Problem solved. Some non-standard character was messing me up. I think I should close this question or I should completely redo it. I have never ever been so utterly wrong about a question. Thank you @r2evans for reminding me of that negated character option thingamabob expression.

Comment: Instead of closing it, I suggest you can self-answer and accept. It can definitely be frustrating when `"string" != "string"`; other recent SO questions had similar problems caused by an "em dash" vs "en dash", most people don't see the nuances of typography to immediately recognize that, and it might help them if you show the string(s) *before* and *after* your `str_replace_all(.)` fix to see how minor it can really be. Glad you eventually figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I exorcised lurking irregularities.

I used the `stringr` package but I am sure there is a base R equivalent.

```
str_replace_all( string = impact , pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", replacement = "")
```

That square bracket means that every character that is a not (that is what the ^ means) an upper case letter OR a lower case letter OR a digit OR a space gets deleted. After that exorcism, all the problems were solved. `grep`, `grepl` and `%chin%` worked perfectly, as I had expected it to.

Thank you to @r2evans for the suggestion.